# Ignore byte-compiled files without source file

Tags: byte-compilation

I recently refactored my Emacs config, part of which involved deleting some old files which had been byte-compiled.

My new configuration (ab)uses the `load-dir` package to load all my customisation files in a specific directory.  The issue arises when I update my config on a different machine, those old `*.elc` files are still there and loaded by `load-dir`, causing confusion as various settings are being overridden by `*.elc` files.

Is there any way to tell Emacs to only consider loading a `.elc` file if a corresponding `.el` file exists?

Comment: Why are you loading all files in a directory, instead of loading those you want to load?

Comment: @Drew so I don't have to explicitly load them all; I came across the trick whilst I was migrating over to using req-package.

Comment: Does the set of files change much? If not, `M-x list-directory` gives you an editable list, which you can easily change to `require` or `load-library` calls. (Anyway, this doesn't answer your question - I was just wondering.)

Comment: Not really, and even now I can still always manually delete all `*.elc` files and get Emacs to re-byte-compile them all.  I suppose I asked this question more out of curiousity as to if it was possible rather than needing a solution.

Comment: Deleting all `.elc` files seems excessive. You can list all the `.elc` files which do not have a corresponding `.el` file with something like `find . -regex ".*.elc?" | sed 's/\.elc\?//' | sort | uniq -u | sed 's/$/.elc/' | xargs find 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to tell Emacs to only consider loading a `.elc` file if a corresponding `.el` file exists?

I am not sure whether this exact option exists, but the Emacs 24.4+ variable `load-prefer-newer` comes close:

> `load-prefer-newer` is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means `load` prefers the newest version of a file.
>   This applies when a filename suffix is not explicitly specified and
>   `load` is trying various possible suffixes (see `load-suffixes` and
>   `load-file-rep-suffixes`).  Normally, it stops at the first file
>   that exists unless you explicitly specify one or the other.  If this
>   option is non-`nil`, it checks all suffixes and uses whichever file is
>   newest.
>   Note that if you customize this, obviously it will not affect files
>   that are loaded before your customizations are read!
>
> You can `customize` this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
>   version 24.4 of Emacs.

Setting this to `t` will allow you to place newer `.el` files alongside obsolete `.elc` files and Emacs will prefer the former. As the documentation warns, this setting must be changed *before* any of the relevant files are loaded. So, if you want the setting to apply to your `user-init-file`, you must enable it before this is loaded, i.e. in your [`site-run-file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) or similar.

Another solution to this loading problem is provided by the package [`auto-compile`](https://github.com/emacscollective/auto-compile) in the form of `auto-compile-on-load-mode`. Enabling this minor mode causes outdated `.elc` files to be automatically recompiled when they are loaded.

#### Update

Further to OP's comment below, here is one possible approach to solving the issue by advising `require`/`load`:

```el
(defun my--locate-file (base suffix)
  "Search for BASE filename with SUFFIX in `load-path'.
Representations of SUFFIX under `load-file-rep-suffixes' are
tried successively until one succeeds."
  (locate-file-internal base load-path (mapcar (lambda (rep)
                                                 (concat suffix rep))
                                               load-file-rep-suffixes)))

(define-advice require (:before-while (feature &optional filename _noerror)
                                      my-ignore-obsolete-compiled)
  "Do not delegate an obsolete compiled FILENAME to `require'.
FILENAME is considered obsolete if it is byte-compiled but lacks
a source file."
  (let ((base (file-name-base (or filename (symbol-name feature)))))
    (or (not (my--locate-file base ".elc"))
        (my--locate-file base ".el"))))
```

Note that this affects nearly *all* file loading in Emacs, so if left non-byte-compiled it may even double your startup time. You can mitigate this by byte-compiling your `user-init-file` and/or further guarding the calls to `my--locate-file`, e.g. with a `FEATURE`/`FILENAME` whitelist or similar.

Also note that `define-advice` is an Emacs 25 feature - in Emacs 24 you should adapt the code to call `advice-add` directly instead.

Comment: I already have `load-prefer-newer` but it doesn't work in the case of having a `foo.elc` without a corresponding `foo.el` there.

Comment: @ivanm See my updated answer and let me know if the proposal helps at all.